# Shared shopping basket over multiple sites

Tags: php, webshop

I've researched 2 methods that could reproduce the functionality coolblue.nl has.
They have 83 webshops, and all shopping baskets are merged. So if you add a product
to your basket on laptopshop.nl and go to one of their other shops (ie. smartphoneshop.nl) the product is already in your basket.

But how does it exactly work?

- Single Sign on? I guess not, users are not required to log in
- Identifying pixel? But how is the product directly available?
- Unique links? They are not using it.

Can anyone give me some detailed info how i could get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Single Sign on? I guess not, users are not required to log in**

Simply share the sessions between your servers. Store everything in a central memcached server. Only limitation is the cookie placed for one domain, not directly accessable by the other domain. Maybe it's JavaScript / JSONP used to circumvent this.

I personally use memcached too because it's faster, has less disc i/o, can be clustered, integrated into PHP and is dispatched from your webserver.

**Identifying pixel?**

Session IDs are stored per domain, so one domain usually cannot read other domains data (security). You can circumvent this using JSON(P). So you send a JSON(P) request to your central (web)session server and ask it "is there already a session for the user, if yes, return me the id".

You'd simply reuse the session then.

**But how is the product directly available?**

You can be sure all their Shops share the same database server and a unique product id like SKU/EAN.

Comment: So they are probably using a memcached server, but i do'nt have experience with it, i think ill try the JSON method. thanks!

Comment: You don't have to run memcached but it makes session handling easier. Memcached is a simple "database" in memory. The main task is to share the same session between multiple domains. Try to google "php session share multiple domains", gives you a lot ;)